# Completeness of Riemann integrable function space with uniform convergence metric

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Inspired by [this queston/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553677/is-there-integrable-function-sequence-which-is-uniformly-converges-to-not-integr) I thought  it would natural to conclude that the Space of Riemann integrable functions with the metric of uniform convergence do form a complete metric space,but as I couldn't prove it specially because completeness is not invariant by homeomorphism,is my intuition right?

Comment: The other answer is your answer. If $x_n$ is Cauchy with the uniform metric, then it has a limit $x$. Since $x_n \to x$ uniformly, we see that $x$ is integrable. What has invariance got to do with it?

Comment: I just wanted to mention that if completeness was invariant i could prove by showing such space is homeomorphic to another complete space,which is not the case,in short,Thank you for enlightening me.